# How to create 2 curved lines in illustrator that are an equal distance from each other?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create two even lines that follow this roughly drawn curve (in red) here:

[image]

Here is a rough example of how I want the lines to look, only spanning the entire length of the curvy line above. I made these lines by using envelope distort on 2 lines, and then copy pasting a flipped one below.

[image]

This method is obviously kind of obtuse though. I'm totally stumped as to how to accomplish this in an easy way. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Make an art brush which contains 2 or more horizontal lines. Here 2 magenta lines are dragged to the brushes collection and defined to be a new Art Brush. That brush is applied to the blue curve:

[image]

You can release the magenta curves by expanding (Object > Expand Appearance) and Ungrouping. After them you have as many independent curves as your brush had lines.

The next image has the same as the previous, but the lines have bigger distance:

[image]

In the bottom the new strokes are released and more intermediate lines are created by blending (8 steps)

Answer (score 0):

- Copy/Paste in Front the original path
- Increase the stroke weight as many pixels/points as the gap will be
- Expand this duplicated path and set a color stroke with no fill
- Delete the extreme paths of this new shape
- Repeat with this second path the same process to get the next path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit different - I'd use **Offset Path** - but as an **Effect**, and using the **Appearance Palette** to *duplicate* the stroke - this makes everything *live* and ***re-editable***.

You will, if you need the ends open, eventually have to **Expand** and delete the two end segments, but *up until that last choice*, it all remains *live* and editable.

Like so:

Squiggly line:

[image]

**Appearance Palette>Duplicate Stroke** - with that duplicated stroke still selected in the **Appearance Palette**, go up to the menu bar and **Effects>Path>Offset Path**:

[image]

This then means this is one single editable item, and can therefore easily be changed as needed until you're happy with your final design.

[image]

Hope this helps!